# Rutas amigables con htaccess y php

Tags: php, php7, .htaccess, php5

Estoy tratando de hacer un sitio web con rutas amigables

Tengo este archivo **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]*)\/?([a-z0-9]*)\/?([0-9a-z\-]*)$ router.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3
```

Este es el archivo **router.php**

```
$param1 = $_GET["var1"];
$param2 = $_GET["var2"];
$param3 = $_GET["var3"];

$path = $param1;

include "./".$path.".php";
```

Cuando escribo una ruta como esta (con 1 parámetro) todo sale bien:

http://localhost/Rutas%20Amigables/inicio

Pero cuando escribo una ruta como la siguiente (con 2 o mas parámetros) no carga los archivos css:

http://localhost/Rutas%20Amigables/producto/10/papas-rufles

¿Cómo puedo solucionar eso?

Comment: ¿Por qué pensás que debería coincidir con la expresión regular? Claramente no va a coincidir cuando tenga más de 2 `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que estás experimentando con la carga de archivos `CSS` se debe a que estás utilizando rutas relativas en tus archivos `HTML` o `PHP` y, debido a la redirección que se está realizando a través de tu archivo `.htaccess`, estas rutas relativas no son válidas para las páginas que se muestran después de la redirección.

Para solucionar este problema, puedes usar rutas absolutas en tus archivos `HTML` o `PHP`. Esto significa que en lugar de utilizar una ruta relativa como `"css/styles.css"`, debes utilizar una ruta absoluta como `"/css/styles.css"` que comienza desde la raíz del sitio web.

Otra forma de solucionar este problema es agregar una etiqueta base en la sección `head` de tus archivos `HTML`. La etiqueta base le indica al navegador la ruta base que se utilizará para todas las rutas relativas en la página. Por ejemplo, si tu sitio web está en la carpeta "Rutas Amigables", puedes agregar la siguiente etiqueta base en tus archivos `HTML`:

```
<base href="/Rutas%20Amigables/" />
```

Con esta etiqueta base, todas las rutas relativas en la página se resolverán a partir de la carpeta "Rutas Amigables", lo que garantiza que los archivos CSS se carguen correctamente en todas las páginas, incluso después de la redirección.

Además, te recomiendo que uses la función urlencode() de PHP para codificar las rutas amigables antes de utilizarlas en tus enlaces. Por ejemplo, en lugar de escribir:

```
<a href="producto/10/papas-rufles">Papas Rufles</a>
```

Debes escribir:

```
<a href="<?php echo urlencode('producto/10/papas-rufles'); ?>">Papas Rufles</a>
```

De esta forma, garantizas que las rutas amigables se codifican correctamente y se pueden procesar adecuadamente en tu archivo .htaccess.

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar ; [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.

Comment: Traté de poner la ruta absoluta que pones de ejemplo: href="/css/estilos.css" y no funcionó pero he definido una función que devuelva la ruta base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/css/estilos.css" y esto si funciona, no se si esto que he hecho también sea valido

Comment: Como esta respuesta viene puramente de ChatGPT, se debería borrarla.